# Constructor confusion

Tags: syntax, constructor, dart

This is part of class  Balls that come from Dart samples(clock sample):

```
  DivElement root
  num lastTime;
  List<Ball> balls;
```

Balls() :

```
lastTime = new Date.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,           
balls = new List<Ball>() {                           \\I do not understand here, why use                               
root = new DivElement();                             \\ List<Ball>(){...}
document.body.nodes.add(root);
makeAbsolute(root);
setElementSize(root, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Because I do not understand, I change constructor :

```
    Balls() {

    lastTime = new Date.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    balls = new List<Ball>() ;
    root = new DivElement();
    document.body.nodes.add(root);
    makeAbsolute(root);
    setElementSize(root, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

  }
```

The application still work. Are there different between constructor `Ball():` `and Ball(){}`?. Thanks.
Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions should work fine. The code in `:` notation is ran before the constructor body, so it's often used for things like calling the super:

```dart
class Person {
  String name;

  Person(this.name);
}

class Employee extends Person {
  Employee(name) : super(name) {
    print('ran after the super call');
  }
}
```

I think the function body is a cleaner approach and I believe the "balls" example wanted to show off different styles, because you could initialize the values inline as well.

I usually use the function body approach unless it looks cleaner or I'm calling parent constructors.

**Update:** Ladicek added fair points. You may initialize `final` fields inline or within the initializer list. And unlike some languages, in Dart there's a guarantee the fields will never be in uninitialized state. It's also good to remember that initializers are run in the order they are listed.

Comment: The code after the `:` is called _initializer list_ and it's actually extremely important. It's the way how Dart fixes the initialization issues that Java or C# has with their constructors -- inside the constructor body, you can pass `this` to any other code while the instance isn't yet fully initialized. That's how you can observe a `final` field in Java to have _two_ values. That's why the initializer list is so important: Dart requires you to initialize all `final` fields in the initializer list (unless they are initialized "inline" in their declaration), which prevents these issues.